# My recursion does not work if I change the function input?

Tags: c++, recursion, input, stack-overflow

My recursive function stops execution and does not work at all. But if I change the input formula of the recursion, then it works perfectly fine. Can someone tell me where am I doing wrong?

I mean, if I use **n/2** instead of **(n+1)/2**  and **(n-1)/2** in the recursion formula then it works. More clearly if I use;

```
return 2*f(n/2)+f(n/2)+7*n-7
```

instead of

```
return 2*f((n+1)/2)+f((n-1)/2)+7*n-7
```

then it works, otherwise, it stops the execution. Why does this happen?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

int f(int n) 
{ 

    if (n == 1) 
        return 2; 
    return 2*f((n+1)/2)+f((n-1)/2)+7*n-7; 

} 

   int main () 

{      int n;
       cout<< " enter odd integer n value "<<"\n";
       cin>> n;
       cout<< "Total Cost is: "<< f(n)<<"\n";
       getchar(); 
       return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This appears to be C++ from your code, but make sure to mark the language as a tag and/or in your question somewhere

Comment: Oki  thanks for the reminder. I just forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what is happening when n=3.

First you call f(3), which in turn will call f(2) and f(1).

Then f(2) calls f(1) and f(0).

f(1) works correctly because of your base case, but f(0) goes on to call f(0) and f(-1). And so your recursion goes on forever.

The correct fix depends on what the function is supposed to be doing, but one possibility you could consider is making the base case n <= 1 instead of n == 1.